# Storing Matrices from console in MIPS Assembly

Tags: matrix, mips, memory-alignment

I am trying to store two 3x3 matrices input by the user in MIPS so that eventually I can perform matrix multiplication. I can store the MatrixA just fine but when I try to store MatrixB I get the error

```
Exception occurred at PC=0x00400060
Unaligned address in store: 0x10010009
```

I know there is a memory alignment issue but how do I fix that?

Here is my code so far (I am using QTSpim to run it):

```
.data
matrixA: .space 9
matrixB: .space 9



.text

main: 
la $a1,matrixA  #load a pointer to array into $a1
la $a2,matrixB  #load pointer to array into $a2

addi $t1,$t1,9  #size of the array(matrix in array form)
addi $t3,$t3,9  

matA_loop: 
addi $t1,$t1,-1   #subtract 1 from $t1, save to $t1 
li $v0,5          #load 5 into $v0 (read integer) 
syscall           #input from user
sw $v0,0($a1)     #store input int to array 
addi $a1,$a1,4    #add 4 to $a1, save to $a1 
bnez $t1,matA_loop     #if $t1 isn't zero,goto loop 
la $a1,matrixA       #load array pointer into $a1 

matB_loop: 
addi $t3,$t3,-1   #subtract 1 from $t3, save to $t3
li $v0,5          #load 5 into $v0 (read integer) 
syscall           #prompt for input 
sw $v0,0($a2)     #store input int to array 
addi $a2,$a2,4    #add 4 to $a2, save to $a2 
bnez $t3,matB_loop     #if $t1 isn't zero,goto loop 
la $a2,matrixB       #load array pointer into $a1 

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly, you need to specify alignment:

```
.data
.align 4
matrixA: .space 9
.align 4
matrixB: .space 9
```

Also, if you use size `8` instead of `9` in both cases, then it will be OK without specifying `.align`. Perhaps, you should read a good article on memory alignment to keep it in mind next time. The trick is that you use `sw` ("store word") instruction to store a *machine word*, which is `4` bytes. So, the address of the memory where data is stored must be a multiple of 4. In your case `0x10010009` (where `MatrixB` starts) is not a multiple of `4`.

Although you don't ask for a code review, I should warn you that you reserve `9` **bytes**, not **words** of memory per each matrix.
This simply means that your code might overflow since in the code below you add `4` byte offset per each element address.

Comment: Oh I did not realize that I was storing bytes (I'm very new to mips). Since I'm storing 9 bytes i changed it to .space 36 and now it works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're always welcome.

> `Oh I did not realize that I was storing bytes` >
To be precise - just to put it in right terms, - you were storing *words* since you were using `sw` instruction. But the storage was insufficient to contain 9 words (9 bytes instead of 36 bytes). So now you've discerned it.